# Wso2 CEP 4.1.0 sample is not working

Tags: centos, windows-10, wso2, wso2-cep

To start the first sample application , i tried to do the prerequisite part by using [this link](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP410/Setting+up+CEP+Samples#SettingupCEPSamples-Prerequisites). And according to that after running `./wso2cep-samples.sh -sn 0101`

> stream-definitions.xml

file should be created inside

> /repository/conf/data-bridge/

. But it didn't happen. i tried in both linux and windows. But results are same. What can i do for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently documentation is not updated properly it needs to fixed. Please refer sample 0101 documentation [1]. In this sample output will be printed in the terminal by using a logger publisher.

On the other hand from WSO2 CEP 4.0.0 on wards sample artifacts is being stored under samples directory. So stream definition of sample 0101 is stored at CEP_HOME/samples/artifacts/0101/eventstreams

[1] https://docs.wso2.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=49777902